# Detect when async.queue finished

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, dns, queue

I'm adding a lot of domain names into async.queue (https://github.com/caolan/async), then doing dns lookups. For some reason the drain event from the async library is being called too soon, either right at the start of the queue or soon after. I want to know when the queue is actually finished so I can use the results.

If someone can recommend another library or method to queue jobs I don't need to use this async library, I just want to get this working.

```js
const dns = require('dns');
const async = require('async');
const MaxConcurrent = 2; // only do x DNS lookups at one time
const MaxWait = 1000; // wait for a second before dns timeout


var dnsQueue = async.queue(function(domain, lookupAgain) {
setTimeout(
function() {
dns.resolve(domain, function (err, address) 
{
console.log('domain: ' + domain + " address: " + address)
});
lookupAgain();
}, MaxWait);
}, MaxConcurrent);


// This should run when the queue is finished
dnsQueue.drain = function() {
console.log('done??');
}

// Array of domain names
var uniqueDomains = [
'google.com',
'yahoo.com',
'ask.com',
'cnn.com',
'real.com'
];

// Push each domain name into the dnsQueue
uniqueDomains.forEach(function(domain) {
dnsQueue.push(domain);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are working on nodejs v7.6 and above then you might as well try async/await.
Below is an example of using async/await in a nodejs application:

```
async function fun1(req, res){
  let response = await request.get('http://localhost:3000');
    if (response.err) { console.log('error');}
    else { console.log('fetched response');
}
```

In the above example, the code asks the javascript engine running the code to wait for the `request.get()` function to complete before moving on to the next line to execute it. The `request.get()` function returns a Promise for which user will await. Before async/await, if it needs to be made sure that the functions are running in the desired sequence, that is one after the another, chain them one after the another or register callbacks.

For more information on async/await follow below links:

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-async-await-in-node-js/
- https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/
- https://javascript.info/async-await

Answer (score 3):

I have created an async queue system for you: https://github.com/rehat101/queue.js

You don't need to explicitly push or drain. You can run the job and it will push and flush for you. This is useful if you don't care when the jobs are completed.

Try to clone the repo and do this:

```
import Queue from './src/queue';
import Promise from 'bluebird';

const { Resolver } = require('dns').promises;
const resolver = new Resolver();

let domains = [
'google.com',
'yahoo.com',
'ask.com',
'cnn.com',
'real.com'
];

(async function() {
    let queue = new Queue({concurrency: 1});
    domains.forEach(domain => queue.run(async () => {
        await Promise.delay(1000);
        console.log( await resolver.resolve(domain) );
    }));
})().catch(console.error);
```

You can add thousands of jobs and it will create 1000 unresolved promises instantly but it will only resolve the promises at the level of concurrency.

I have plans to add more features and put it up on npm.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of you have put `lookupAgain()` before its `dns.resolve` finished.
Just changed the position of `lookupAgain()`.

```
const dns = require('dns');
const async = require('async');
const MaxConcurrent = 2; // only do x DNS lookups at one time
const MaxWait = 1000; // wait for a second before dns timeout


var dnsQueue = async.queue(function(domain, lookupAgain) {
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      dns.resolve(domain, function(err, address) {
        console.log('domain: ' + domain + " address: " + address)
        lookupAgain();
      });
    }, MaxWait);
}, MaxConcurrent);


// This should run when the queue is finished
dnsQueue.drain = function() {
  console.log('done??');
}

// Array of domain names
var uniqueDomains = [
  'google.com',
  'yahoo.com',
  'ask.com',
  'cnn.com',
  'real.com',
  'google.com',
  'yahoo.com',
  'ask.com',
  'cnn.com',
  'real.com'
];

// Push each domain name into the dnsQueue
uniqueDomains.forEach(function(domain) {
  dnsQueue.push(domain);
});
```

I have checked this is working fine.

Comment: I've tried this and for some reason I'm always getting MaxResult number of results still coming in after the dnsQueue.drain has said it is finished. I thought it was an async issue (dns results finishing after) but I set a long time out of 5 seconds before returning anything in the drain and it's still happening.